# Comparing and manipulating webform results

Tags: webforms

I'm trying to set up a webform survey (all multiple choice) that allows people within a community to be matched with a partner that shares similar interests to them.

Essentially, I'm looking for a way to compare results from a webform so that I can determine matches between submissions. Once a match has been found, I'd like to delete those submissions (Or effectively remove them from the pool of submissions).

Is that possible with webform, or should I be looking for another module/method? Initially I was looking for a way to feed webform responses into a SQL table, but that doesn't seem to be possible.

Comment: This is a too broad question. You have to record submits (with webform or any other method), then set up a task to compare each submissions with all other (or all other not yet matched), send the email, remove the mathed submissios form task.... not to mention how to compare submissions (what kind of fields, multiple, coinditonal, etc).

Comment: Right, I was worried about that. Originally, I was trying to find a way to feed webform submissions into a sql table, but that doesn't seem to be possible.

Primarily I'm looking for a way to compare and match the responses, which would be multiple choice questions.

Comment: I don't know any module that performs that matching .